# How can I load credentials.json file into jenkins pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a script which runs against google Directory API.

The purpose of this script is to download all users from Google's Directory of our company.

But when I run that script it give an error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'
```

Although that file is in the folder.

Do I need to put that file into the Credential manager or ....?

I also have a groovy file which just install the pip and activate venv and nothing else.

Here is groovy code

```
stage('Check activity') {
      steps {
        sh 'pwd'
        sh '''#!/bin/bash
          set -e
          if ! which pipenv >/dev/null; then
              echo \'no pipenv, installing...\'
              pip3 install --user pipenv
              if ! which pipenv >/dev/null; then
              # default location for: /home/jenkins/.local/bin/pipenv
              my_pip_env="/home/${USER}/.local/bin/pipenv"
              fi
          else
              echo \'pipenv already installed, nothing to do.\'
              my_pip_env=$(which pipenv)
          fi
          # pipenv version, check & install
          ${my_pip_env} --version
          ${my_pip_env} install
          # run script
          PYTHONPATH=$(pwd):${PYTHONPATH} \\
          PIPENV_PIPFILE=$(realpath ./Pipfile) \\
          ${my_pip_env} run -v python3  ./it/google-users/google_user.py -v "${VERSION}" -dr "${DRY_RUN}" -et "${EXCLUDED_TYPES}"
          # Remove virtualenv project
          ${my_pip_env} --rm
        '''
      }
    }
```

do I need to define environment variables in groovy script?

Comment: have a look in the file folder for all your workspaces- you have to consider that the workspace may not be the same one if you have multiple nodes. my experience tells me that you have to think about how and when you do such operations,

Answer (score 0):

When reading a file from your workspace, it is best to use [readFile function](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace)

```
readFile('credentials.json')
```

In your case, you could read it into a variable and then pass it into the next steps of your script. Something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Check activity')
        {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh '''#!/bin/bash
                       echo "hello" > hello.txt
                    '''
                    def mydata = readFile('hello.txt')
                    sh "echo My file data: ${mydata}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Suresh but I want to know that how groovy script can pass that 'credentials.json' to my script? and it can run it? 
or do I need to install credentials binding plugin and then I can add withCredential attribute in my groovy file?

Comment: @bizimunda Thanks for the code snippet. I've provided a better example based on that. I don't think you need withCredentials because from code perspective it is just a file generated by some code and it doesn't matter if it has actual credentials or not.